# What are some tips for apologizing to my CEO for missing a very important meeting?

Tags: professionalism, communication, meetings

So this morning, I went to my office expecting to attend this HUGE meeting (overview and intro to procedures on a large grant my organization has been awarded) and learned, too late, that the meeting was actually being held at the grantor's offices instead if at ours.  I texted my boss - who was at the right location - my mixup and he angrily told me not to come: it was unacceptable to arrive at a meeting that important even 5minutes late.

Now I feel awful - the details of the meeting were clearly stated on the email appointment but I instinctively went to our offices anyway.

What to do?  How to address this with my CEO and/or the Grantor's!

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: @gnat I'm not sure this question runs afoul of the guidelines--I would say that OP might reword it to make it clearer that it doesn't, though.  Maybe say "How do I proceed after making a small error made me miss an important meeting?".  That is definitely asking advice on how to do something, it's likely that someone else will have the same question in the future (I've done similar things myself).  It's hard for me to believe people aren't going to give advice that will be useful to the general population.

Comment: This seems pretty relevant: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21099/i-missed-a-meeting-because-i-misread-the-email-how-should-i-approach-this?rq=1

Comment: Next time, as a sanity check, confirm to your boss that you are going the meeting at [state the location and time] before the meeting happens. If you get the location or time wrong, your boss - or someone who is going to the meeting, will correct you immediately. Anyone can make a mistake, and I think that your boss's temper tantrum is out of place. At any rate, what's done is done. Put it behind you, you have plenty of work that needs to be done to look forward to. And getting that work right will, in the long run, will be far more important to the organization than missing some meeting.

Answer (score 3):

You're human. It happens. Apologize, explain, promise it won't happen again, get growled at, and move on. There is no magic here, just learning and improving.

Consider getting a PDA or other alarm that will remind you before important events.

Comment: +1 - It's happened now and there's little else you can do apart from apologise and ensure it doesn't happen twice. If it makes you feel better, I once had an appointment with a hard-to-pin-down client arranged and, on that day, I went mental and drove 75 miles in the wrong direction before I realised my mistake. We all got over it :)

Comment: Admitting to your mistakes gives you credibility, as long as you aren't a habitual mistaker. Definitely don't just ignore it. You don't want a reputation of passing the buck or not admitting when you screw up. If you feel that you probably should apologize then you definitely should apologize.